# ViewData Compilation Error : BC30203: Identifier expected

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have code below.

```
    public ActionResult PatrList(decimal PAT_ID)
    {
        ViewData["PAT_ID"] = PAT_ID;
        return View(); 
    }

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var PAT_ID = '<%= ViewData["PAT_ID"].ToString() %>';
        $("body").data("PAT_ID", PAT_ID);
    });
</script>
```

Unfortunately, I got Compilation Error : BC30203: Identifier expected.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below line to top of the view page, then it works perfect.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var PAT_ID = '<%= (ViewData["PAT_ID"]).ToString() %>';
        $("body").data("PAT_ID", PAT_ID);
    });
</script>
```

or better in Razor engine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var PAT_ID = '@(ViewData["PAT_ID"]).ToString()';
        $("body").data("PAT_ID", PAT_ID);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it shows "Compiler Error Message: BC30491: Expression does not produce a value." after change code to your way. tks.